# Corda - Contract verification using oracles

Tags: corda

I was going through the official documentation and while going through https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-contracts.html I came across the following statement.

> Transaction verification must be deterministic - a contract should either always accept or always reject a given transaction. For example, transaction validity cannot depend on the time at which validation is conducted.

As far as I understand, this means that transaction verification should be independent of when the transaction was being verified.

Later on, in the same page I saw the following:

> Sometimes, transaction validity will depend on some external piece of information, such as an exchange rate. In these cases, an oracle is required.

This seems to be conflicting with the earlier statement. If I use exchange rates for contract validation, wouldn't the validation become non-deterministic?

If I use the exchange rate for EURUSD as one of the parameters for contractual validation, that parameter would vary over time and a state update valid today may not be valid in the future due to change in rates.

Is there something that I've misunderstood here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an Oracle, it is a neutral node who signs over a transaction if it met its requirements/validation.

On the contract itself, you're only enforcing that the Oracle's signature must have been used to sign over the transaction, it doesn't check the non-deterministic fact that was validated by the oracle, it can be any arbitrary information/fact i.e exchange rate. So in that sense, for `Contract Validation`, it is still deterministic.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes, transaction validity will depend on some external piece of information, such as an exchange rate. In these cases, an oracle is required.

This process works as follows:

- A party requests the external piece of information
- The party includes the external piece of information in their transaction of part of a command
- The oracle only signs the transaction if the external piece of information is true at the time they sign

Thus an oracle's signature asserts that the external piece of information was valid **at the time it was included**, even if it has changed since (e.g. a changing exchange rate). Thus contract verification remains deterministic.